# How do I read tagger information from a GIT tag?

Tags: git, git-tag

So far I have:

```
git rev-parse <tagname> | xargs git cat-file -p
```

but this isn't the easiest thing to parse. I was hoping for something similar to `git-log`'s `--pretty` option so I could grab just the info I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has already been answered a long time ago but still is the top search result even though it's not the best solution anymore, so here it goes:

**Command:**

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/$TAG --shell --format='
TAG=%(refname)
TYPE=%(objecttype)
COMMIT=%(objectname)
TAGGER=%(tagger)
EMAIL=%(taggeremail)
DATE=%(taggerdate)
CONTENTS=%(contents)
'
```

**--shell** does the quoting for Shell scripts. There is also **--perl**, **--python** and **--tcl**.
If you don't want to write whole format as a command line option, you can also put it in a **file.txt** and do this:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/<tag> --shell --format="$(cat file.txt)"
```

**Output:**

```
TAG='refs/tags/4.1.0-RC1'
TYPE='tag'
COMMIT='973cc103f942330550866588177fe53ea5765970'
TAGGER='ml_'
EMAIL='<ml@example.org>'
DATE='Fri Sep 16 14:14:50 2016 +0200'
CONTENTS='Release 3:
* INSTALL.md added.
* GIT.md modified.
'
```

More information here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref

Comment: I think this is the best answer now (better than my accepted answer)

Comment: Note that `TYPE` will be `commit` for a lightweight tag.

Answer (score 43):

A more direct way of getting the same info is:

```
git cat-file tag <tagname>
```

This uses a single command and avoids the pipe.

I used this in a bash script as follows:

```
if git rev-parse $TAG^{tag} -- &>/dev/null
then
    # Annotated tag
    COMMIT=$(git rev-parse $TAG^{commit})
    TAGGER=($(git cat-file tag $TAG | grep '^tagger'))
    N=${#TAGGER} # Number of fields
    DATE=${TAGGER[@]:$N-2:2} # Last two fields
    AUTHOR=${TAGGER[@]:1:$N-3} # Everything but the first and last two
    MESSAGE=$(git cat-file tag $TAG | tail -n+6)
elif git rev-parse refs/tags/$TAG -- &>/dev/null
then
    # Lightweight tag - just a commit, basically
    COMMIT=$(git rev-parse $TAG^{commit})
else
    echo "$TAG: not a tag" >&2
fi
```

Comment: I think the newer answer using `git for-each-ref` is a better solution nowadays

Answer (score 35):

`git show $TAG` will show you the information for the tag, as well as the commit it points to.

If you have something that already works for you, but is unwieldy to type, you could always set an alias:

```
[alias]
        showtag = !sh -c 'git rev-parse $1 | xargs git cat-file -p' -
```

And call it with:

```
$ git showtag my-tag-name
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned I also managed to get as far as `git show --quiet --pretty="format:" $TAG` but that's mostly the same as above.

Comment: @quornian: You could use Git's alias functionality. I provided an example in my answer.

Comment: thanks, it works well!  Just want to remind the readers that `alias` need to be added to file `.gitconfig`, normally it's in your home folder.  And if you don't have a newline after this `git showtag` executed, you can add it by:  `showtag = !sh -c 'git rev-parse $1 | xargs git cat-file -p && echo ""' -`